# regex either / or

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that could have email address in two different ways

```
way 1: str = " text text. Recipient: test@test.com";
way 2: str = " text text. Recipient Email: test@test.com";
```

In javascript I am using the following to see if there is an email address

```
test.match(/Recipient:\s(\w+@\w+.\w+)/);
```

but this works only for way 1 where its Recipient. I want to match  it for  either Recipient Or Recipient Email.

How would I modify the above to support both clauses?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add this to your regex

```
(?: Email)?
```

The non-capture group is a little more explicit than other solutions provided here

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
test.match(/Recipient( Email)?:\s(\w+@\w+.\w+)/);
```

This makes the " Email" part optional.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
( Email)?
```

Will optionally match " Email", (a ? means the preceding item 0 or 1 times) so adding that in we have:

```
test.match(/Recipient( Email)?:\s(\w+@\w+.\w+)/);
```